# How to combine two zoo objects in R

Tags: r

I have 2 zoo objects of the same length, one with dates.

```
> a
           Number
2007-01-01      5
...

> b
1 10
...
```

How to add b as a column in a?

```
            Number   b
2007-01-01       5  10
```

Or create a combined object with both as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future please provide your data in reproducible form.  We have assumed the data `a` and `b` shown below.

```
library(zoo)

# inputs
a <- zoo(cbind(Number = 5), as.Date("2007-01-01"))
b <- zoo(cbind(10))

ab <- cbind(a, coredata(b))
names(ab) <- c(names(a), "b")
```

giving:

```
> ab
           Number  b
2007-01-01      5 10
```